# Create folder in using dropbox api for android

Tags: android, dropbox-api

Does anyone know how to create folder programatically using dropbox api for android??I am not using sync api.I have managed to upload images and files but I am unable to create folder.

This is my upload asynctask:

```
public class UploadFile extends AsyncTask<Void, Long, Boolean> {

    private DropboxAPI<?> mApi;
    private String mPath;
    private File mFile;

    private long mFileLen;
    private UploadRequest mRequest;
    private Context mContext;
    private ProgressDialog mDialog;
    final static private String ACCOUNT_PREFS_NAME = "prefs";

    private String mErrorMsg;


    public UploadFile(Context context, DropboxAPI<?> api, String dropboxPath,
            File file) {
        mContext = context;

        mFileLen = file.length();
        mApi = api;
        mPath = dropboxPath;
        mFile = file;

        mDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        mDialog.setMax(100);
        mDialog.setMessage("Uploading " + file.getName());
        mDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        mDialog.setProgress(0);
        mDialog.setButton("Cancel", new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // This will cancel the putFile operation
                mRequest.abort();
            }
        });
        mDialog.show();
    }


    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            // By creating a request, we get a handle to the putFile operation,
            // so we can cancel it later if we want to
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(mFile);
            String path = mPath + mFile.getName();
            mRequest = mApi.putFileOverwriteRequest(path, fis, mFile.length(),
                    new ProgressListener() {
                        @Override
                        public long progressInterval() {
                            // Update the progress bar every half-second or so
                            return 500;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onProgress(long bytes, long total) {
                            publishProgress(bytes);
                        }
                    });

            if (mRequest != null) {
                mRequest.upload();
                return true;
            }

        } catch (DropboxUnlinkedException e) {
            // This session wasn't authenticated properly or user unlinked
            mErrorMsg = "This app wasn't authenticated properly.";
        } catch (DropboxFileSizeException e) {
            // File size too big to upload via the API
            mErrorMsg = "This file is too big to upload";
        } catch (DropboxPartialFileException e) {
            // We canceled the operation
            mErrorMsg = "Upload canceled";
        } catch (DropboxServerException e) {
            // Server-side exception. These are examples of what could happen,
            // but we don't do anything special with them here.
            if (e.error == DropboxServerException._401_UNAUTHORIZED) {
                // Unauthorized, so we should unlink them. You may want to
                // automatically log the user out in this case.
            } else if (e.error == DropboxServerException._403_FORBIDDEN) {
                // Not allowed to access this
            } else if (e.error == DropboxServerException._404_NOT_FOUND) {
                // path not found (or if it was the thumbnail, can't be
                // thumbnailed)
            } else if (e.error == DropboxServerException._507_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE) {
                // user is over quota
            } else {
                // Something else
            }
            // This gets the Dropbox error, translated into the user's language
            mErrorMsg = e.body.userError;
            if (mErrorMsg == null) {
                mErrorMsg = e.body.error;
            }
        } catch (DropboxIOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            // Happens all the time, probably want to retry automatically.
            mErrorMsg = "Network error.  Try again.";
        } catch (DropboxParseException e) {
            // Probably due to Dropbox server restarting, should retry
            mErrorMsg = "Dropbox error.  Try again.";
        } catch (DropboxException e) {
            // Unknown error
            mErrorMsg = "Unknown error.  Try again.";
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Long... progress) {
        int percent = (int) (100.0 * (double) progress[0] / mFileLen + 0.5);
        mDialog.setProgress(percent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        mDialog.dismiss();
        if (result) {
            showToast("Successfully uploaded");
//          mApi.getSession().unlink();
//
//          // Clear our stored keys
//          clearKeys();
        } else {
            showToast(mErrorMsg);
        }
    }

    private void showToast(String msg) {
        Toast error = Toast.makeText(mContext, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        error.show();
    }
    private void clearKeys() {
        SharedPreferences prefs = mContext.getSharedPreferences(ACCOUNT_PREFS_NAME, 0);
        Editor edit = prefs.edit();
        edit.clear();
        edit.commit();
    }



}
```

Please help.

Comment: how are you calling the method to upload and what is the value of "dropboxPath"?

Comment: UploadFile upload = new UploadFile(DropboxDownload.this,mApi, DIR, filefordropbox);

Comment: DIR IS "/" ,FILEFORDROPBOX IS THE FILE TO BE UPLOADED

Comment: I have added the answer, which works for me by the way, not sure if an answer should be so small, but I think it'll work for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the `createFolder` method of `DropboxAPI`. See https://www.dropbox.com/static/developers/dropbox-android-sdk-1.6.1-docs/com/dropbox/client2/DropboxAPI.html#createFolder(java.lang.String).

Comment: What should be the dropbox path??is it "/"??

Comment: It should be whatever path you want to create a folder at. E.g. `/foo` to create a folder called `foo`.

Comment: sir,please have a look at this :   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27046540/dropbox-confirmation-dialog-pop-up-every-times-when-button-is-clicked

Answer (score 2):

According to dropbox documentation

```
try {
      // creating folder
      val fo = client.files().createFolderV2(File.separator + folderPath)
     } catch (ex: CreateFolderErrorException) {
            if (ex.errorValue.isPath && ex.errorValue.pathValue.isConflict) {
                // folder already exist
             }
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply give like this for creating a folder! its very simple

```
 dropbox.putFile("Mynumber2/myregion2/"+"/"+"A"+"/"+"B"+"/"+"ENTRY.db", fileInputStream,file.length(), null, null);
```

if you do, mynumber2-->myregion2-->A-->B will be your folder structure created on dropbox!

Comment: such a simple but elegant answer

Answer (score 0):

Use the following for DIR:

"/your_folder_name/"

Comment: please post what you see for path from the following: `String path = mPath + mFile.getName();`